# Location look up database like foursquare, Yelp , Google places , Facebook graph API etc

Tags: facebook-graph-api, foursquare

I am looking for a location database service for my app. I want to the user to be able to search for businesses restaurants etc around them when they start typing in into the search bar.

Facebook Graph API or Foursquare API achieves this, but there are rate limits on making calls to the API every hour. One way around is using Facebook or Foursquare login to login into my app, but then how do I provide the same functionality for users who don't want to register using Facebook or Foursquare.

Ideally I would want to avoid the extra step or logging in through Facebook or foursqaure altogether. (There if they want the convenience of it, but not mandatory - but access to location look up is mandatory).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion its always best to use Google Places API. This will get rid of the scenario of login through Facebook or foursquare. But this has a limit to the API calls to be made. But in the development stage or if your app is having a small no of audience then the free api call count is enough.

More details can be found in this [link](https://developers.google.com/places/)